# parsing argc and argv in c++

Tags: c++, string, argv

I want to learn more C++... Usually I make a for loop to parse argv, and I wind up with a bunch a C-style strings.  I want to do something similar in C++, but preferably without reading from /proc/whatever.  At first, I tried to convert the C-style string to a C++ style string without results... The frustrating bit is that everyone on SO seems to want to know how to go the other way, which is what c_str() is for.  What's a good C++ way to do this (ie parse argv)?

Also, one note, I'm looking for a unix style answer, all the techniques for conversion I've seen have to do with Windows, which I'm completely uniterested in.

Comment: Just curious... did you get the idea that you need to read /proc from this article?  http://blog.linuxgamepublishing.com/2009/10/12/argv-and-argc-and-just-how-to-get-them/

Comment: no, I did not... I hate the 15 char rule here

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question.

The cleanest method I know to get all the arguments in an easy to use array is:

```
std::vector<std::string> v(argv, argv + argc);
```

But if you're looking for a way to really parse the data, check out [Boost.ProgramOptions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/program_options.html).

Comment: +1 Boost program options is awesome. Makes it so much easier to make a command line application.

Answer (score 2):

Are you having trouble converting argv's to strings? You can just do:

```
string s(argv[i]);
```

...where `i` is a valid index into `argv`.