# Using bubble sort on command line arguments c++

Tags: c++, sorting

I think I am a little confused on bubble sort in general. But my main issue is converting the command line arguments to a typical array as opposed to argv.

I was thinking by looping through the `argv` I could puch.back to a vector then use my bubble sort function it the vector.

I want to sort the names taken in from the command line from A to Z order then from Z to A order.

Any help with my code with be appreciated. 
Please add comments so I can understand better why this has been difficult for me.

Thanks!

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void swap( int [], int, int );
void bubble_sort( std::string args[], int );

void bubbleSort(std::string args[], int n) {
    bool swapped = true;
    int j = 0;
    std::string tmp;
    while (swapped) {
        swapped = false;
        j++;
        for (int i = 0; i < n - j; i++) {
            if (args[i] > args[i + 1]) {
                tmp = args[i];
                args[i] = args[i + 1];
                args[i + 1] = tmp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::string> args(argv, argv + argc);

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        args.push_back(argv[i]);

    }
    long vector_size = args.size( );

    bubble_sort(args,vector_size);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain the down vote and I will edit my question. Thank you.

Comment: we are not compilers. You already posted the expected behavior, but you have to also post the result you get (compiler error, wrong output etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you are mixing up arrays and vectors.  I would review [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) page for how to declare, initialize, and use vectors.  You are creating a `std::vector` in `main`, yet passing a `std::string[]` to `bubbleSort`.  These are not the same type.  If you want to use `std::string[]`, then you need to declare such an array in main, instead of using `std::vector` and `std::vector.push_back()`

While you can use the syntax that you have, I find it's a little hard to understand exactly what it is doing, so I recommend manually filling it with `push_back()`, until you understand vectors more.  As such, if using a vector, `main` would look something like:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    std::vector<std::string> args;

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++){
        args.push_back(argv[i]);

    bubble_sort(args); // Don't really need to pass the length of args, since you can access it using .size()
    // You probably want to actually print this out, for confirmation purposes.
    for(int i = 0 ; i < args.size() ; i++)
        cout << args[i] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Keep in mind that vectors are not passed by reference, so if you do any swapping in `bubbleSort`, those changes will NOT be reflected in main.  Learning about pass by reference is left as an exercise to the reader, but your bubbleSort function signature will look something like `void bubbleSort(std::vector<std::string> &v)`.  Keep in mind that if you're already going to be using `std` functionality, it's not really worth it to use your own sorting algorithm (except for just learning), since there is already [std::sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/).

The other way to do this is to use a regular old array, using your own sorting algorithm, main will be something along the lines of:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    std::string *args = new string[argc];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < argc ; i++)
        args[i] = argv[i];
    bubbleSort(args, argc);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < argc ; i++)
        cout << args[i] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Keep in mind that you CANNOT get the length of a dynamically allocated array with a `.size()` function, so you need to pass the length.  As such, the function signature for `bubbleSort` would look something like: `void bubbleSort(string *args, int len)`

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help. I got it working. I am confused about one part. I am not understanding how were making it sort. For instance if I want to change it from z to a no what specifically is telling it what order to sort it in?

Comment: @NDiaz You should review exactly [how bubble sort works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort)!  Look through the algorithm, and try to figure out what needs to be changed.  Hint: only one character needs to be changed.

Comment: I figured it out thank you for your help. You guys are great.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first convert the input command line arguments to std::string and then you have to push back to the arrays. Once you did it will works as expected.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
   std::vector<std::string> args;//argVec(argv, argv + argc);

   for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
   {
      std::string s = argv[i];//Converting Arguments to std::string
      args.push_back(s);
   }
   long vector_size = args.size();

   bubble_Sort(args,vector_size);
   return 0;
}
```

Also if you want to use std::vector v(argv, argv + argc); then please refer the following links

[parsing argc and argv in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814756/parsing-argc-and-argv-in-c)

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/program_options.html